# script to convert css sheet from px to em

Tags: css, font-size

Anyone know of a script (php, python, perl, bash, whatever) that will convert a stylesheet from px to em?

Like, it would take input of the filename and base font-size (default 16) and convert all px instances to em?

eg:

convertpx2ems --file stylesheet.css --base-font-size 16

would convert this:

```
button {
    font-size:14px;
    padding:8px 19px 9px;
}
```

to something like this:

```
button {
    font-size: .875em;
    padding: .5em 1.188em .563em;
}
```

...maybe, is there a way to do this with sass?

Answer (score 19):

Copy/Paste your css in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neemanjabuge/Rg6qx/) to convert. 
code example:

```
var regFindPX = new RegExp('(\\d+)px','g');
var reg3decPoints = new RegExp('(\.\\d{3}).*', '');

var css = 'css code';
var result;
while ((result = regFindPX.exec(css)) !== null) {
    var px = parseInt(result[1]);
    var em = px / 16;
    em = em.toString().replace(reg3decPoints, '$1');
    css = css.replace(px + 'px', em + 'em'); 

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't sensibly interchange px and em sizes like that. A px size is an absolute value that will remain the same size regardless of where it is. An em size is relative to the parent element, thus 0.5em is half the size of the parent element. If that doesn't make much sense, consider the following piece of code:

```
/* CSS */
span { font-size: 0.9em; }

<!-- HTML -->
<span>Testing,
    <span>Testing,
        <span>Testing</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

In this example you'll find that the word "Testing" gets smaller and smaller because the font size of each span tag is 90% of the one above.

For the body tag, a font-size of 1em is roughly equivalent to 16px, but that is the only time you can sensibly translate one size to another

Comment: I suppose, it depends on how well managed your stylesheet is, but I see the point. That's probably why there isn't one... if there isn't one. Nevertheless, I *could* use such a converter. It would really help me convert existing stylesheets to my method of typography.

Comment: For instance, in a well structured layout, that button (from my example) would only ever be in a context like this: <code>body > section||aside > form > button</code> I would never have a button within a button, etc.

Comment: I don't know of any automatic system but I see no reason why you couldn't write something that scans the HTML output and the CSS and successfully convert all the px sizes into accurate em sizes. God help you if you have any dynamic content though :-P Besides, since all modern browsers zoom into a page instead of simply trying to expand sizes (and keeping px sizes the same) then you'll already have a perfectly good and working layout - personally I'd leave it alone

Comment: I have all dynamic content... The point is that I also have highly structured layouts and well managed stylesheets. I need a quick way to convert existing client stylesheets to ems so that I can re-create them without looking up 100 conversions on charts. Also, the reason people use ems in typography is so that the page scales nicely between UA's *without* user interaction.

Comment: I think manually going through it all and doing the conversions yourself may be the quickest way. Your well structured layouts and style sheets should make the job relatively easy.

Comment: You can set the font-size of body to 67% and reduce the need for conversion charts. When this is done 1.0em = 10px, 1.4em = 14px, 2.0em = 20px and so on, hope this helps even if just a little.

Comment: yeah... I have tried that too, and it is the easiest means of conversion, that's for sure. I'd rather use the base browser em, however. Anyway... if I come across a script or tool for this, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it easily in Perl:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d+)px/($1\/16).em/ge' stylesheet.css
```

Comment: em to px (untested): `perl -p -i -e 's/([\d+.]+)em/($1*16).px/ge' stylesheet.css`

Comment: this is true for rem conversion

Answer (score 2):

I knocked this up in awk:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    bfs = 16;
}

{
    while (match($0, /([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+px/)) {
        num = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH - 2);
        #print("numval: ", numval);
        $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) (num != 0 ? (1 / bfs) * num: 0 ) "em" substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
  }
}

1
```

You can use it to replace any px entries in a file with suitable conversions .. note that bfs must be set to the Base Font Size (16 in this case) that you wish to use.  Also note, you have to have some shell skills to use this properly.

Comment: This script, and the whole idea, make sense if you use 'rem' instead of 'em'. As other posters have suggested, em is a relative unit, so you can't convert from px. But rem is an absolute unit, and this script works for that purpose!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but I thought this might help someone:

**Convert px to em:** 
target ÷ context = result

**Ex:**

To find the value of 1px & say the font-size for the container is 16px the equation would be as follows:

1 ÷ 16 = 0.0625~

(It's best to round to the nearest thousandth.)

1px = 0.063em

From this you can also find other measurements by target * em_value = result

**Ex:**

10 * .063 = .63

10px = .63em

I hope this makes sense & helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

As James points out, the issue with any straight-up converter is that the stylesheet is unaware of which elements are nested. Because `em` values are relative, the computed `font-size` will be varied in heavily nested elements. You would need a tool that scanned the HTML output after it had been rendered, and recursively adjusted the relevant styles.

I've written a JavaScript component that could prove helpful in this regard. You can grab it [here](https://github.com/shennan/emify).

Suggested workflow would be to call `emify(document.body)` in the browser, and then extract the relevant `em` values and inject it back into your css.

Not ideal, but it's one way of doing it with accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

From the previous discussion, it seems as though no online generator exists, right?  I sure couldn't find one that would parse the entire stylesheet.

First, if em is applied to and image, or input, aside from the font inside an input, would they be relative, and if so, what and how?  Images can't be nested, and I have a hard time seeing them being relative to every parent div width.  (Conversion for the sake of CSS PIE, to avoid errors, is what is inspiring this).

Aside from just input and images, I was wondering if there ways a way to convert an entire stylesheet. Help me to see if my logic would work.  I think I have several of the elements already created, I would just need to tack them together.

Working with the CSS alone can't do the trick, as it's impossible to know which elements will be nested. So it would require scanning the html output.  What's the best way to do that?  The only way I could think of is to apply all the styles inline, which a  [generator](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) has been made to convert templates for emails and such.  Once styles are inline, this would show how everything is nested.  From that, compare to stylesheet.

Compare each nested element with "em" to any parent element with "em" to generate the px accordingly, and I already have a regex tool to parse the css, making this easier.

The one problem is that a class can be nested under different elements, the em in a single class becoming different in it's context, thus impossible to convert to px and be applied the same.  The only solution, I believe, is to recreate the nested structure, or a portion of, in the css sheet to apply the px accordingly, anytime the font size differs in context.

For example:

```
<code>
    // Original Stylesheet
    .mainClass{font-size:1em;}

    // HTML
    <div id="outerNest" style="font-size:.5em;">
        <div class="mainClass"> Font here is .5em </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mainClass> Font here is 1em</div>

        // New stylesheet 
    .mainClass{font-size:16px;}

    // newly created styles to work with px conversion
    #outerNest .mainClass{font-size:8px;}
</code>
```

A. Do you think that could work?
B. Is there a better way?
C. Is it in any way worth it?  I could have used it once in a blue moon in some random situations, but I doubt many people would find it of any value.  Or is there a situation in which it would be handy in which people do run into here and there?

Answer (score 0):

#### I have created a *powershell* script for this task.

It is a script that parses a CSS file which its `font-size` rules are written with units of `px`, and converts them to `font-size` with `rem` units.

**You are welcome to use it:**

**https://github.com/taljacob2/convert-css-fontsize-px-to-rem**